# Morphia equal ignoring fields

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

I have a class as follows:

```
@Entity 
public class Wrap{
    private Metadata meta;
    // And more ...
}
public class Metadata{
    private List<Image> images;
    private String price;
    private Integer value;
    // And more ...
}
public class Image  {
    private String url;
    private String hash;
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int h = 7;
        h = 89 * h + Objects.hashCode(this.hash);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Image other = (Image) obj;
        return (!Objects.equals(this.hash, other.hash));
    }
}
```

The normal query `ds.createQuery(Wrap.class).field("meta").equal(otherMetadata);` will compare all the fields (as expected).

As you can see in the code, the class Image overrides equals&hashcode in order to ignore the field `url`. That works for Java. But there is a way in morphia to query (using .equal or .filter or anything else) ignoring some fields?

Answer (score 0):

`equal()` is a comparison in MongoDB. `equals()` is the comparison in Java. The two do not interact.

You'll need to put together a more complex database query with `.field("meta.price").equal(meta.getPrice())` and so on.

Comment: I know equal and equals are different. I just wanted to highlight how I did it for Java.

And your solution is what I thought...but since my object is quite complex and also extends from others, I don't think is a good solution at all.

Comment: If you need this for many entities you could probably extract the information via reflections and automatically generate your database queries. Unfortunately, I'm not aware of a readily available solution.

Comment: Morphia is using reflections to create the query I posted. I could add a annotation and do not add those properties to the query. I just thought there may already be something like that